# Progress Dialog not Shown

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have this code snippet, the problem with this code is that when I click the 'done' button 
the ProgressDialog is not showing.Please help

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.send);


        done = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendbut);

        done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {             

            public void onClick(View v) {

                 showProgressDialog();
                 query_str = getString();
                         startUploading();
            }
        });          
 }

 public void showProgressDialog(){
     GlobalClass.printLine("Showing progress dialog"); 
     progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Send.this);
     progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
     progressDialog.setMessage("Sending...");
     progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
     progressDialog.show();  
     // Start lengthy operation in a background thread
     new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
                 // Update the progress bar
                 mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                         progressDialog.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Herererererer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         if(mProgressStatus == 100){                                             
                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                             progressDialog.dismiss();
                         }
                     }
                 });                                 
             }
     }).start(); 
 }
```

Comment: nobody is going to directly understand your code. you should describe what you want to do and where you are getting problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `AsyncTask` ?

Here is the doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You may want to replace the thread with the AsyncTask.

Comment: Yah I tried it but the same thing happens as I explained above.

Comment: onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute are executed after the two functions getString();
          startUploading();

Answer (score 0):

You should use AsyncTask which is also known as [Painless threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Now, to show progressbar while processing in background, here is an example:

```
    // ASync Task Begin to perform 
 private class performBackgroundTask extends Async Task < Void, Void, Void >  
 {
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog( this);

    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
           // here you have place code which you want to show in UI thread like progressbar or dialog or any layout . 
           Dialog.setMessage(" please wait...");
           Dialog.show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
       // write here the code to download  or to perform any background task.
   return null;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
     Dialog.dismiss();  // here we have to dismiss the progress dialog 
   // To display fetched data in textview, imageview, or any

  }

 }
```

Comment: I think you have to initiate with `MainActivity.this` instead `this`

Answer (score 0):

@Hari..

I think you are calling another functions from inside  startUploading(),that's why ProgressDialog is not shown. Try creating the progressBar in XML and write all functions inside the button click. If that is a recursive function change your logic to call this inside the button click itself.

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted above by Paresh Mayani will not work since you can't use

```
new ProgressDialog(this)
```

in the AsyncTask. "this" needs to be a Context.